# Fail to render in DirectX programming

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-development, directx-9

For a little bit of context, I am a student that just started in studying game programming via C++ and D3DX. So when I was working with OO structure in my code, I encounter some problem regarding to rendering a texture in my homework.

As below:

```
//Source.cpp
#include "MainMenu.h"

int main() {

    Window* wnd = new Window();
    D3DX* directX = new D3DX();
    DirectInput* dInput = new DirectInput();
    stack<GameState*> gsm;

    wnd->createWnd();
    directX->createD3DX(wnd);
    dInput->createDInput(wnd);
    
    gsm.push(new MainMenu());
    gsm.top()->init(directX);

    while (wnd->wndIsRunning()) {
        gsm.top()->getInput(dInput);
        gsm.top()->update(dInput);
        gsm.top()->render(directX, dInput);
    }

    dInput->cleanupDInput();
    directX->cleanupD3DX();
    wnd->cleanupWnd();
    return 0;
}
```

```
//GameState.cpp
#include "GameState.h"

void GameState::getInput(DirectInput* input)
{
    input->getDInput();
}

void GameState::render(D3DX* directX, DirectInput* input)
{   
    directX->getDevice()->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    directX->getDevice()->BeginScene();

    directX->getBrush()->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

    D3DXVECTOR3 mousePos = input->getMousePosition();
        //cout << mousePos.x << endl; 
        //this line is to test the position is valid.
    directX->getBrush()->Draw(directX->getCursorTexture(), NULL, NULL, &mousePos, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));

    directX->getBrush()->End();

}
```

```
//D3DX.cpp
#include "D3DX.h"

bool D3DX::createD3DX(Window* wnd)
{   

    IDirect3D9* direct3D9 = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dPP;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dPP, sizeof(d3dPP));

    d3dPP.Windowed = isWindow;
    d3dPP.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dPP.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dPP.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dPP.BackBufferWidth = wnd->getWidth();
    d3dPP.BackBufferHeight = wnd->getHeight();
    d3dPP.hDeviceWindow = wnd->getHandle();

    hr = direct3D9->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, wnd->getHandle(), D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &d3dPP, &d3dDevice);

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        cout << "DirectX 3D Device creation failed!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    hr = D3DXCreateSprite(d3dDevice, &spriteBrush);


    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        cout << "DirectX 3D Brush creation failed!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(d3dDevice, "assets/genshin_cursor.png", &mouseCursorTexture);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout << "Failed to load texture!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
        
}

void D3DX::cleanupD3DX()
{
    mouseCursorTexture->Release();
    mouseCursorTexture = NULL;

    d3dDevice->Release();
    d3dDevice = NULL;
}

IDirect3DDevice9* D3DX::getDevice()
{
    return d3dDevice;
}

LPD3DXSPRITE D3DX::getBrush()
{
    return spriteBrush;
}

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 D3DX::getCursorTexture()
{
    return mouseCursorTexture;
}
```

So I've checked stuff below:

1. the file is there, in the samedirectory/assets/thefile
2. For input part, passing in the pointer for it work fine
3. Output mouse position on console, it should be in the middle of the screen

I expect it to render out, obviously.
The only problem I could think of is when returning the device/brush/texture there is something wrong, but I can't figure it out. I wish to get some guidance or hints.

Edit:
My entire code file till now if need more details
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1grFz8n_CTxbnnTkVbzUhTi1iix8tmJu3?usp=sharing

Comment: If you start with DirectX, why don't you start with DirectX11 or DirectX12 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/changes-in-dx9-legacy-hardware-support)? You may get more help, for example in my personal case I don't help on DirectX9

Comment: Well, its my syllabus I have no choice, this is actually my homework too, I should've mentioned that in my question, sorry @simon

Comment: You need to fire your teacher if they are teaching you DX9. You'd be better off learning DX11 on your own.

Comment: I mean this is just to learn how game engine basically work in raw coding and we shall shift to game engine next sem to learn 3d game dev. Anyway thanks for any advice, it might be useful for my future career.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am a big idiot, I forgot to device->present. Forget my idoity.

So basically, in my previous code, I missing the most important part of rendering and I totally ignored it. Which

```
//GameState.cpp
#include "GameState.h"

void GameState::getInput(DirectInput* input)
{
    input->getDInput();
}

void GameState::render(D3DX* directX, DirectInput* input)
{   
    directX->getDevice()->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);
    directX->getDevice()->BeginScene();

    directX->getBrush()->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

    D3DXVECTOR3 mousePos = input->getMousePosition();
        //cout << mousePos.x << endl; 
        //this line is to test the position is valid.
    directX->getBrush()->Draw(directX->getCursorTexture(), NULL, NULL, &mousePos, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));

    directX->getBrush()->End();

}
```

I should add a directX->getDevice()->EndScene() and directX->getDevice()->Present() at the
end;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).